# how to access json obj using data attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a data-attribute for several element. I just want to access the JSON obj using data attribute in jquery.

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="plans" data-plan="state-1"><span class="pricing-symbol">$</span>20</div>
   <div class="plans" data-plan="state-2"><span class="pricing-symbol">$</span>30</div>
   <div class="plans" data-plan="state-3"><span class="pricing-symbol">$</span>40</div>
   <div class="plans" data-plan="state-4"><span class="pricing-symbol">$</span>50</div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
var pricing_list = {
    "US":{
        "symbol":"$",
        "state_1" : 20,
        "state_2" : 20,
        "state_3" : 20,
        "state_4" : 23

    },
    "BRL":{
        "symbol":"R$",
        "state_1" : 210,
        "state_2" : 220,
        "state_3" : 203,
        "state_4" : 123
    },
    "EU" : {
        "symbol":"€",
        "state_1" : 210,
        "state_2" : 20,
        "state_3" : 23,
        "state_4" : 123
    }
   }

function getCountry(obj){
    if (typeof google !== 'undefined' && google.loader.ClientLocation){
        var currentLocation = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
        return (currentLocation in obj) ? currentLocation : 'US';
    }

    return 'US';
}
    var cur_country = pricing_list[getCountry(pricing_list)];

    $(".pricing-symbol").html(cur_country["symbol"]);

    console.log('.plans');
```

Now I got the currency symbol for all the element. And now dynamically, I want to implement the pricing using data-attribute. Pls help me with this....

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 var cur_country = pricing_list[getCountry(pricing_list)];
 $(".pricing-symbol").html(cur_country["symbol"]);

$('.plans').each(function () {
    var nodes = $(this).contents();
    nodes[nodes.length - 1].nodeValue = cur_country[$(this).data('plan').replace('-', '_')]
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rbTD8/)